# delete undeline from Link in nextJs

Tags: next.js

How can I find the line under the word in the link

```
        <Link
          style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "white" }}
          href={`/products/${id}`}
        >
          More Details
        </Link>
```

Comment: i think you are looking for ```textDecoration: "underline"```

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work, how can i add or delete

Comment: textDecoration: "underline" it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to wrap you're text into `<a> </a>` tag. according to `Next Js` docs [Docs Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children). Have a look at this code i hope it will work for you.

```
   <Link
      style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "white" }}
      href={`/products/${id}`}
    >
     <a> More Details </a>
    </Link>
```

> it's working in my case one more mistake in you're code is , you have to use `as keyword` for dynamic route

```
 <Link href={`/products/[id]`} as= {`/products/${id}`} > </Link>
```

[image: code]

[image: Demo]

Comment: also it doesn't working

Comment: yes thisis answer but i add textDecoration: "none" in anchor